# How does browser session monitoring work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, session

I was using http://mouseflow.com/demo/ , it actually records a whole browsing session of a user (including mouse movements, clicks, keystrokes ect). I am wondering how this technology actually works. Collecting mouse clicks and mouse movements is easy, however how could they generate a video file?

```
Theory:
1. They track mouse movements, mouse clicks, ect.
2. Recreate the user session on their servers while using a video recording tool like Camstudio
3. Save the video file.
```

But my theory doesn't make too much sense because they create the video too fast for the 'recreation' step.

So, how exactly does this work?

Comment: Is it literally a video file? (i can't visit the site for some reason). It wouldn't be too difficult to just move a cursor graphic around interacting with an interface, mimicking what you did. This is done all the time in collaborative software/applications.

Comment: I can't wait until widespread adoption of touchscreens makes this technology worthless.

Comment: @Blaze Works quite well on touch devices too, actually.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's not a video. It's the same page loaded in an iframe, with the movements/clicks I made replayed.

Neatly, the same code that tracks can be used to playback, so the 'video' cursor, clicks and keystrokes are interacting with the real page.

This is a pretty cool way to do this.

To verify, pop open your web inspector on the playback page.

Comment: Doesn't that violate cross-origin policy?

Comment: Not if the iframe is of the same origin... Even if it weren't, there's ways around that too if you own both domains.

Comment: Well i know that. How do they do it then? Do they `wget` the website they are tracking, store it on their servers, then re-create the video?

Comment: Obviously, these guys don't own both domains.. I don't think you know how it works do you

Comment: The way I've described is how it works. The JS code is hosted by the tracking company, so it can do what it wants. They can just set the CORS headers correctly. The JS is in the iframed page, not on the page the iFrame is embedded in.

Comment: If they use CORS then the domain that they are requesting to must also enable CORS

Comment: Just look at the code – they embed JS from their server that does both tracking and replay.

Comment: Then how does it work when the content of the website changes then?

Comment: Does it work in that case? If so, then there is more going on. The demo definitely works as I've described – you can see what's happening by using the dev tools. If it works even when content changes, then they likely store the HTML alongside the mouse/keyboard trace.

Comment: Mouseflow uses both mouse/keyboard events and HTML contents for recordings. That way you can playback recordings with "old" contents. There are two modes: simple and session-support. Simple means that the HTML content is crawled. Session-support means that the HTML is sent from the recording script.